# Get Json Object from external URL with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an URL that returns the JSON object below:

```
{
    "addressList": {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "id": 0000000,
                "receiverName": "Name Example",
                "country": {
                    "id": "BRA",
                    "name": "Brasil"
                },
                "state": {
                    "id": "SP"
                },
                "city": "São Paulo",
                "zipcode": "00000000",
                "type": "Residential",
                "street": "000, St Example",
                "number": 00,
                "neighborhood": "Example",
                "hash": "1bf09357",
                "defaultAddress": false,
                "notReceiver": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get the `state` value, how can I retrieve that with PHP?

I tried, something like this, but I couldn't get the `state` value, that should be `SP` in this case.

```
$string = '{ "addressList": { "addresses": [ { "id": xxxxxx, "receiverName": "XXXXX XXXXX", "country": { "id": "BRA", "name": "Brasil" }, "state": { "id": "SP" }, "city": "São Paulo", "zipcode": "03164xxx", "type": "Residential", "street": "Rua xxx", "number": xx, "neighborhood": "xxxxx", "hash": "xxxxx", "defaultAddress": false, "notReceiver": false } ] } }';

        $json_o = json_decode($string);

        $estado = $json_o->state;
```

How can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: its under addressList, addresses (first index), state, then id, you can't just outright use state, its not inside the parent level, use `print_r / var_dump` to find out

Comment: Note that "octal and hexadecimal formats are not used" for number in JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid - you can validate it on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) (*it's invalid due to incorrectly formatted numeric values - `"id" : 000000`*).

From then on, you can decode the value and access your data:

```
$json_o = json_decode($string);

$estado = $json_o->addressList->addresses[0]->state->id;
```

---

If you don't have access to the code that generates the JSON, you can attempt to run a regex to match, replace & wrap the numerical values with `"`:

```
$valid_json = preg_replace("/\b(\d+)\b/", '"${1}"', $str);
```

<sup>***Note:*** *The above is just an example - you'll have to figure out a case where a numerical value is already wrapped by `"`.*</sup>

Comment: @JoyCooper My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has a couple of syntax errors:

```
"id":     0000000
"number": 00
```

JSON doesn't support leading zeros. If precise formatting is important, use strings:

```
"number": "00"
"id":     "0000000"
```

Alternatively, use well-formed integers in the JSON (saves space) and convert them to formatted strings in PHP.

Once you've fixed your JSON, you can access the `state->id` value of the first address as I do below. When you decode JSON from an untrusted source, be prepared to do some error handling:

```
$json_string ="..."; //your source, to be decoded

$json_o= json_decode($json_string);

if(is_null($json_o)): //there was an error decoding        
    $errno = json_last_error();
    $err_msg = json_last_error_msg();
    die("Json decode failed: Error #$errno: $err_msg");
endif;
//we get here if json_decode succeeded. To get "SP", do...
$stateID = $json_o->addressList->addresses[0]->state->id;
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it doesn't answer the question of how to access the `state` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$json_o = json_decode($string, true);
$estado = $json_o['addressList']['addresses'][0]['state']['id'];`

Comment: Run `echo json_last_error()` after `json_decode()`.  What output do you get?

Comment: I got just the number `4` as output.

Comment: I already got it working with @Darren's answer, thank you anyway.